# MongoDB data folder backup and restore between different Mongo versions

Tags: mongodb, database-backups

Some background: we build and ship our Mongo application, which customers can then install at their location or their choice of cloud

We provide customers a way to take backup and restore their data. The mongo is pretty huge, so the mongodump and restore are not feasible. For this reason, we started directly copying the mongo data folder and restore. This seems to be working fine, but later in new release we upgrade the mongo version and if we let the customer restore directly with data folder of older version, seems this will not work always???

I found few threads which say if it works then it will be just by luck, although there are ways to recover like spinning old version and upgrade mongo and bring the data folder with new version ( But this will be tough process )

Is there any way which can guarantee a seemless process? Like mongo itself can detect the old data and upgrade or by putting some compatibility flags?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you are trying to achieve. Have you seen this, though? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-revision/ Also, why is mongodump and -restore not an option? What problems are you running into? Would Ops Manager be an option? https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/

Comment: @DevC sorry for providing an answer but rather asking a question...You were restoring mongo db from a data folder if i understood you correctly? Could you give me some pointer on how you did that because i am in a similar situation as you were, not sure about the versions yet :) thanks up front

Answer (score 2):

**Considerations:**

Upgrading mongodb from one version to another must need to go with following [checks](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-upgrade-replica-set/#upgrade-recommendations-and-checklists) that directly linked to the data compatibility:

- Is your data compatible when you restore datafile from version A to version B by copying files?
- Sometimes upgrading involves a [change in the index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-compatibility/#stricter-validation-of-collection-and-index-specifications) or setting up protocol version which needs manual verification to resolve conflicts.
- Feature compatibility versions: Some of the newer versions need to set [setFeatureCompatibilityVersion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-upgrade-replica-set/#enable-backwards-incompatible-newversion-features) flags to utilize the backward compatible features when the likelihood of a downgrade is minimum.
- Is there any intermediate release that is required before upgrading from one version to another? For example to upgrade the mongodb version from 2.6 to 3.2 and an [intermediate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/#upgrade-requirements) upgrade to 3.0 is required
- [db.upgradeCheck()](http://www.mongoing.com/docs/reference/method/db.upgradeCheck.html): This tool is handy that can help you to understand the checks.

**Approach**:

Considering your use case where your users get control on mongodb deployments you can:

- Evaluate a mongodb data compatibility by copying files from one version to another when the new version is available as upgrades are not too frequent.
- Evaluate if there are any manual actions required in cases like [index updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-compatibility/#stricter-validation-of-collection-and-index-specifications)
- Generate a compatibility matrix that guides your users on the data compatibility from one version to another
- Additionally, an upgrade document can be created to ensure hassle-free data restore if there are any flags need to set in order to restore data from one version to another

Answer (score 1):

I will start with an assumption since you stated that recently you have upgraded that you are now on MongoDB version 3.6 (or 4.0?).

Which is great but that version is not compatible with 3.4 without settings [some admin flags](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/). [Here are the compatibility changes in detail](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-compatibility/).

Now what is done in this case is you would have to set this in order to get the database to be compatible back with 3.4:

```
db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4" } )
```

This would make it work with previous versions but at the cost of not utilizing the 3.6 features.

You can see what `featureCompatibilityVersion` you are on with:

```
`db.adminCommand( { getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1 } )`
```

If this helps and you are now done with the changes you wanted you can then set back the `3.6` compatibility by doing the same `setFeatureCompatibilityVersion` command with this time with `3.6` value. Now this is tested and works well with 3.4 to 3.6 and vise versa. If your version is lower it is still worth a try :).

From the docs on what this would do when done on 3.6:

> If set on MongoDB 3.6 deployments, Disables the 3.6 features that
>   persist data incompatible with MongoDB 3.4.

In conclusion I am assuming we are talking about 3.6 to 3.4 but this would still be true for 4.0 to 3.6 etc. You still would have to try this and see if it benefits you in any way. Hope this helps.